# Search a trigger into a google script project

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like a better way to search a specific trigger into the triggers of a google script project.
The classic way is:

```
 function triggerSearch() {
  
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
       
    if (allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "<function_name>") {
      
      //...
    }
  }
 
}
```

I see that in ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers() there is the methode indexOf(search element); how can I format the "search element" for searching a specific trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don’t want to use a `for` loop and construct an array of all the triggered function **names**, then you can use `map` and `includes`:

```
function triggerSearch() {
  
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var allTriggerNames = allTriggers.map(tr=>tr.getHandlerFunction());
  
  if (allTriggerNames.includes("<function_name>")){
  // code when the trigger is applied to "<function_name>"
  }
 }
```

`includes` can be used in the same way as `indexOf`.

Remember `getProjectTriggers()` gets all installable triggers associated with the current project and current user. Therefore, it is an **array** and you can use every JavaScript method you want that can be applied to arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. In your opinion, which solution is more fast and convenient?

Comment: @Michele for a big number of triggers the second would be faster. Either way, more convenient. For loops are enjoying sometimes and you have to define extra variables.